# Organizing Jenkins Libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using [Jenkins Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) in our pipeline development. We have written quite a few libraries inside it and now we want to organize it little better. Is it possible to have folder structure within vars folder of jenkins shared libraries?

Comment: you can create self sub folder under `src` folder.  Like you create java package.

Comment: Hi @yong. Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Shared library project folder structure:

[image]

As above picture, you can organize folder structure in `src` folder, just like organize java package.

Then import them inside `vars` folder where we declare global variable.

2) Content of `vars/acidReleaseProcess.groovy`:

```
#!groovy

import com.fmr.pipeline.AcidReleaseProcess

def relProcess

/**
 * Create a instance of class: AcidReleaseProcess
 * 
 * @param  appName uDeploy Application Name
 * @param  compName uDeploy Component Name
 * @param  compVersion component version to deploy
 * @return A self reference
 */
def call(appName, compName, compVersion) {
    relProcess = new AcidReleaseProcess(this, appName, compName, compVersion)   
    return this
}

/**
 * Execute Install, Go Live and Stop process on specify env
 * 
 * @param  envName name of environment to delpoy, exmaple: 'DIT', 'PAC', 'XQ1'
 */
def blueGreenDeploy(envName) {
    relProcess.deployToPassive(envName)
    relProcess.swapPassiveToActive(envName)
    relProcess.stopPassive(envName)
}
```

3) `com.fmr.pipeline.AcidReleaseProcess.groovy`

```
class AcidReleaseProcess implements Serializable {

    def script, appName, uDeployVers, passiveGroup = [:]

    AcidReleaseProcess(script, appName, compName, compVersion) {
        this.script = script 
        this.appName = appName
        this.uDeployVers = compName + ":" + compVersion
    }

    def deployToPassive(envName) {

        script.echo "Checking uDeploy environment ${envName} group state"

        script.sh 'docker pull ...'

        script.withCredentials([script.string(credentialsId: '<...>', variable: 'UDEPLOY_AUTH_TOKEN')]) {

            def group1_state = script.sh(
                        returnStdout: true, 
                        script: "docker run --rm -i ... \
                                    -a ${appName} \
                                    -e ${envName}-${group1} " + '-t ${UDEPLOY_AUTH_TOKEN}'
                    ).trim()

            def group2_state = script.sh(
                        returnStdout: true, 
                        script: "docker run --rm -i ...y \
                                    -a ${appName} \
                                    -e ${envName}-${group2} " + '-t ${UDEPLOY_AUTH_TOKEN}'
                    ).trim()

            script.echo "${envName}-${group1} is ${group1_state}, ${envName}-${group2} is ${group2_state}"

            if("${group1_state}" == "Live" && "${group2_state}" == "Live") {

                script.echo "Environment: ${envName}, ${group1} and ${group2} both are Live," +  
                     "only allow install on Non-Live environment"

                script.sh 'exit 1'
            } 

            def groupName = "${group1_state}" != "Live" ? group1 : group2

            passiveGroup[envName] = groupName
        }


        def uDeployEnv = envName + '-' + passiveGroup[envName]

        script.echo "Install on ${uDeployEnv}"

        script.step([
            $class  : 'UCDeployPublisher',
            siteName: 'pi_udeploy_srvpiudupload',
            deploy  : [
                    $class:             'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
                    deployApp:          appName,
                    deployEnv:          uDeployEnv,
                    deployProc:         UDEPLOY_INSTALL_PROC_NAME,
                    deployVersions:     uDeployVers,
                    deployOnlyChanged:  false
            ]
        ])
    }
}
```

4) we should keep content of files in `vars` folder as simple as possible, and organize reuse-able or complex code into class file under `src` folder.

5) some tips:

1. Pass-down pipeline object to class in src folder

   `relProcess = new AcidReleaseProcess(this, appName, compName, compVersion) 
    // this is the pipeline object`
2. Store the pipeline object in class contructor function
   `AcidReleaseProcess(script, appName, compName, compVersion) {
           this.script = script // script here is the pipeline object`
3. All global name need prefix with the pipeline object: `script`

   `sh -> script.sh
   echo -> script.echo
   with... -> script.with...
   string -> script.string
   etc...`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for this @yong. I was looking for folders inside vars but this makes much more sense.

Comment: @yong: are you using basic steps in your classes under src? I also have had the plan to put in all the repeating code etc under src but the syntax here is not as easy as within steps. Did you had the same experiences? For example calling withMaven  surrounded by withCredentials within a class.

Comment: You need to pass-down the global pipeline object from `var` into `src` when you new object of `src`.  I give the code of class: `AcidReleaseProcess` for your reference with some modify to hidden sensitive information from my code.

Comment: @yong You are awesome! thanks a lot :D I didnt know that its possible to use the steps just by referencing them from the script-object.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around all this but this is one of the better explanations i've seen. To tie it all together, would a step in the `Jenkinsfile` call `blueGreenDeploy(the_env_name)` to use it?

Comment: When you use `Scripted Jenkinsfile`, only need to call `blueGreenDeploy(the_env_name)` like invoke a function.  When you use `Declartive Jenkinsfile`, you need wrap the call inside `script` step, like  `script { blueGreenDeploy(the_env_name) }`

Answer (score 0):

As @yong stated, you can set up a package structure under `src/` folder.  The main disadvantage from my point of view is, that its more complicated to implement steps here because you have to write more code to get the same result as with custom steps under `vars/`. As written on the website, its best to use for helper functions.
What we did:  grouping custom steps under `vars/` in one script-file like in this example for all logging actions:

vars/log.groovy (example you can find at the website)

```
def info(message) { 
   echo "INFO: ${message}" 
} 

def warning(message) { 
   echo "WARNING: ${message}" 
}
```

You can use env vars and steps as much as you want in it. To use the methods in your jenkinsfile you have put them inside steps and script block and call them with `filename.method`.

If directories under `vars/` are possible i dont know. Did you try it?

Comment: directories under vars/ are not possible